# Python: Rerun try-except loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to rerun a try-except loop each time there is an error and only break when there is no error.

```
loop = True;
    while loop == True:
        try:
            for i in data_names:
                #do something
        except Exception, e:
            e = str(e)[0:100];
            parse_error_list.append(str(e)[str(e).rindex(':')+2:str(e).rindex(':')+4]);

            if len(e) == 0:
                loop = False;
```

As a sanity check, will the following allow me to exit the loop if and only if there is no error?

EDIT: Is the answer? If so, is this the most efficient implementation? ...

```
loop = True;
    while loop:
        try:
            for i in data_names:
                #do something
        except Exception, e:
            e = str(e)[0:100];
            parse_error_list.append(str(e)[str(e).rindex(':')+2:str(e).rindex(':')+4]);

        if e:
            loop = False;
```

Comment: The indentation seems to be messed up. Can you please fix the indentation in the code.

Comment: the only break condition I can see is if the string representation of your exception is 0-length; i.e. never.  Also using *actual* `break` is a much saner way to break out of a loop than specifying a variable to do it for you.

Comment: Like the following?
try:
               for i in data_names:
                    #do something
            except Exception, e:
                e = str(e)[0:100];
                parse_error_list.append(str(e)[str(e).rindex(':')+2:str(e).rindex(':')+4]);
                break;               Why doesn't len(e) == 0 for no error break the loop?

Comment: because the `except` block never happens if there's no exception.  You're checking `len(e)` inside the `except` block..

Comment: except Exception, e:
            e = str(e)[0:100];
            parse_error_list.append(str(e)[str(e).rindex(':')+2:str(e).rindex(':')+4]);

if len(e) == 0:
    loop = False;

Ah right. Would the above work?

Comment: @Blackholify, why not post an answer here ;)

Comment: @zhangxaochen Not sure if this is the correct answer though.

Comment: The "pythonic way" to write `while loop == True:` is: `while loop:` and the same goes for: `if len(e) == 0:` --> `if e:`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The neatest solution would probably resemble:

```
while True:
    try:
        for i in data_names:
            #do something
    except Exception, e:
        #log or otherwise handle exception
    else:
        break
```